# CSS Footer with an overflow scrollbar

Tags: html, css, footer

I suppose the easiest way to show this would simply be to give a link to the website where it needs to be added.

I **NEED** a simple footer that is always stuck at the bottom of the page, no matter how much content is placed within the main **CONTENT** and **SIDEBAR** divs.

I've tried using the sticky footer, and a few other methods. Such as putting it at the bottom of the page with bottom 0, etc.. But, with my setup it never seems to work. If you need anymore information feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi. I am a bit unsure what you are trying to accomplish here. As I understand, you want a bottom bar kind of thing that is scrollable ?

Comment: kindly give the information clearly wat u want to be fixed.

Comment: I need a footer, a simple footer for the copyright and referral links of the site. Like any other site has, but the problem is.. It never sticks at the bottom of the page no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the css of your site to this one...this may help you...

```
#Wrapper {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
}
#Banner {
    height: 169px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#Navbar {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#Outer {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
#Sidebar {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 12.5%;
}
#Content {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-height: 65%;
    width: 85%;
}
#Copyright {
    background-color: #FF3333;
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: That is the same problem as the one above, it is a fixed footer. I also uploaded an example of what that would come out as on my website. I need something that is on most major websites, the footer that is always at the bottom of the page no matter how much content is added. But it is at the bottom of the page, not stuck to the bottom of the view port, if that makes sense.

Comment: mostly dont use position:absolute; the problem is becos of float and absolute only...

Answer (score 0):

Ok what you want is a css class that looks more or less like this.

**EDIT**

```
.MyBottomBasicClass {
     position: relative;
     bottom 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
     Width: 100%;
     height : 300px // or whatever... 
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow: scroll; 
 }
```

**EDIT**

You also need to wrap your other content.

```
.wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
 }
```

and...

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

now in your html...

```
<div cssClass="wrapper">
         //       your site content
</div>
<div cssClass="MyBottomBasicClass">
         // here you enter all the information you may need to include copyright  information
</div>
```

Comment: Well, if I placed a 'fixed' position it would always be there no matter where I scrolled. Which isn't what I am looking for. The big trick is getting it to ONLY show up when you've scrolled to the bottom of the page. Using a FIXED position causes it to always be at the bottom of the view port, which isn't really a footer per say.

Also, I uploaded the example of a basic 'FIXED' position footer to the website.

Comment: what happens With the new changes ?

Comment: I uploaded the new changes, and you can see them on the site. Basically the same problem, only it is stuck to the top of the page now.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, and the attempts. ^^

Comment: its a pleasure, I had to try. remember to upvote the answer! I'll upvote you to get rid of that negative vote

Comment: Thanks, and yeah.. I'd give you a useful answer if I could. Either way, thanks. ^^